# RAD 7.5 Web Service question

Tags: websphere, rad

I'm using Rational Application Developer to create some web services.  The problem I have is I follow the instructions laid out in a screen cast, however when I get to the part where I pick "JAX-WS" it complains that Websphere does not have an implementation for the webservice libraries as the chosen server is only a "stub".

Being new to developing for WAS, I was wondering what this means?  Is it that RAD does not ship with an actual implementation of WAS, but only stub libraries so your code can compile?  Is it that I need to install a full blown WAS server locally in order to test my webservice code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured this out, had to go into IBM Installation Manager and pick the WAS 6.1 and Web Services feature.